# Unable to connect to SeleniumWebDriver through Perl

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver

I have written a simple Perl script to launch google. But it terminates with an error - Could not connect to SeleniumWebDriver at C:/perl/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 220

I am using selenium server version - 2.31
OS - windows7 (32 bit)

**Perl Code**

```
   use warnings;    
   use strict;
   use Selenium::Remote::Driver; 
   my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( browser_name => 'firefox', port => 4444,
                                      platform => 'ANY');
   $driver->get('http://www.google.com');
   sleep(5);
   print $driver->get_title();
   $driver->quit();
```

When i execute perl script, at each instance, on server command prompt i could see this line -
14:07:23.325 INFO - Executing: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.Status@
8e96fc at URL: /status)
14:07:23.327 INFO - Done: /status

But browser is not getting launched. Please can anybody help me about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the selenium server on a machine with firefox and X (assuming Linux)

and maybe add the proxy in

```
{remote_server_addr=>'localhost', port=>4444,proxy => { 'proxyType' => 'system' }}
```

can you post how you're starting selenium

Answer (score 0):

I started the selenium server using command 
"java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar"

But the issue get resolved now. I guess it was Perl issue. I was using Active Perl V 5.16.
Then i installed Strawberry Perl V 5.18 and it worked.

Thank you!